# How to diagnose crash report

Tags: ios

I have a UIViewController：DFUserChatViewController witch is inherit form DFChatViewController，in DFChatViewController init method I have a navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem with a method backAction

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
       ...........

       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[DFBarBackButtonItem alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) image:nil] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in DFUserChatViewController I overwrite the method backAction：

```
#pragma mark - action
-(void)backAction:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    .............any other thing  
    .............
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

I use crashlytics for crash report and today I receive a crash

```
0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4000000c
raw
0
libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 5
1
DFmyPro     
DFUserChatViewController.m line 349
-[DFUserChatViewController backAction:]
2
UIKit    -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
3
UIKit    -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
4
UIKit    -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
5
UIKit    -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
6
UIKit    -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
7
UIKit    -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
8
UIKit    -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
9
DFmyPro 
DFShakeWindow.m line 46
-[DFShakeWindow sendEvent:]
10
UIKit    -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
11
UIKit    _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7098
12   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
13
CoreFoundation   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
14
CoreFoundation   __CFRunLoopRun + 622
15
CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
16
CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17
GraphicsServices     GSEventRunModal + 138
18   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
19
DFmyPro 
main.m line 15
```

main

I run my app again and again ，and didn‘t catch the crash ，How do I know where goes wrong

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding you... The first block of code and the back button outlet are from DFChatViewController, but the second block of code is from DFUserChatViewController which inherits *from* DFChatViewController?  Could you post DFChatViewController's backAction: method?

Comment: DFChatViewController has his own backAction: method implementaion,and DFUserChatViewController just overwritten it